# Write a function that takes, as an argument, a list, and returns a LIST that duplicates the elements in the list

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function which takes an input for example [1, 2, 3] and returns [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3] but I'm getting an error

here is the code I have now

```
def problem3(aList):
    list1= []
    newList1= []
    for i in range (len(aList)):
        list1.append(aList[i])
    for i in range (0, len(list1)):
        newList1= aList + list1[i]
```

This is the error

> "Traceback (most recent call last):
>   Python Shell, prompt 2, line 1
>   File "h:\TowlertonEvanDA7.py", line 34, in 
>   newList1= aList + list1[i]
>       builtins.TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list"

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
def problem3(aList):
    newList1= []
    for i in aList:
        newList1.extend((i, i))
    return newList1

lst = [1,2,3]
print problem3(lst)

# [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "add" an integer to a list; this works only for two lists.

```
newList1 = aList + list1[i]
```

Could be any of the following:

```
newList1 = aList + [list1[i]]
newList1 = aList.append(list1[i])
newList1 = aList.extend([list1[i]])
```

Note, however, that these will not fix your program -- they'll merely allow it to run.  Your logic doesn't build the new list in the proper order.  It currently would produce [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3].

You need logic that will add an element twice *as soon as you first touch it*.  The critical statement would be something like:

for item in aList:
        newList.extend([item, item])

Answer (score 0):

Your second for loop should be like:

```
    newList1.append(aList[i])
    newList1.append(list1[i])
```

or even:

```
    newList1.append(aList[i])
    newList1.append(alist[i])
```

so list1 is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can not combine a list with an element. 
Second, the first for loop is not necessary.

You can do it like this:

```
    def problem3New(aList):
        buffer = aList
        newList = []
        for a,b in zip(aList, buffer):
            newList.append(a)
            newList.append(b)
        return newList
```

Answer (score 0):

Based off the error you're getting it looks like you're mixing your types (i.e. you're trying to **add** an integer with a list).

As noted in the second for-loop of your code, you have:

```
    newList1= aList + list1[i]
```

Which is saying:

`Set newList1 to list1 plus whichever element we're looking at now`

You probably looking to instead **append** two of the current element you're looking at to `newList1`.

For what's probably the most straightforward way of doing this (without modifying your code too much):

```
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    # append current element twice to the end of our new list
    newList1.append(list1[i])
    newList1.append(list1[i])
```

Make sure to also `return newList1` at the end of your function (or else you won't see your result from wherever you called `problem3`).

You can definitely simplify this code however

```
def problem3(aList):
    newList1 = []

    # iterate over list by its elements
    for x in aList:
        newList1.append(x)
        newList1.append(x)

    return newList
```

There are many different ways (most that are better) you can write this solution out however.